# Shell Script for loop stops after the first iteration (very simple code)

Tags: bash

I'm very new to shell script. I'm learning the basic of it. My very simple for loop is not working. It always stops at the first iteration. I already follow the document to create an array variable and using for loop with super simple code.

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=()
LIST+=('aaa') 
LIST+=('bbb') 
LIST+=('ccc') 

for i in $LIST
do
    echo '----------'$i'----------'
done
```

It only show **'aaa'** then stop the loop. I really have no idea. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$LIST` expands to the first element in array `LIST`, it's basically the same thing as `${LIST[0]}`. You need to use `${LIST[@]}` in double-quotes to get each element as a separate word, like:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=()
LIST+=('aaa') 
LIST+=('bbb') 
LIST+=('ccc') 

for i in "${LIST[@]}"
do
    echo '----------'"$i"'----------'
done
```

c.f. [Bash Reference Manual § Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)